# what is crittercism_v3_0_3_sdkonly used in jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu?

Tags: android, slidingmenu

what is crittercism_v3_0_3_sdkonly used in jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu?
why is this library need for this https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/tree/all-sides/example project?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely not needed, just added by the developer to help them track issues / errors 
https://www.crittercism.com/